# Crud/CakePHP: placing findMethod in the controller

Tags: cakephp

I am referring to this documentation:
https://crud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actions/index.html#findmethod

Is there a way to place the find method in the controller, instead in `App\Model\Table`?

*What I want to achieve:*
I want to apply a filter in the `index` action, depending on some conditions. This means for example, that the pagination for `Users` should show only users whose name begins with a specific letter and this letter will be provided when the page is refreshed and will always change.

If it's not possible, is there a way I can apply this filter before any data is loaded from the database?

---

I tried this code in `UsersController.php`, but the table shows always all rows. I apparently don't understand how it works.

```
public function index()
{
    $users = $this->paginate($this->Users->find()->where(["id" => 1] ));
    $this->set(compact("users"));
    return $this->Crud->execute();
}
```

But, when - for testing - I use an unknown field in the `where` condition [for example `bar`] then I get this - correct - error message:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'bar' in 'where clause'
```

So, apparently, the where condition is applied but for some reasons all rows are returned instead of only 1 row with `id = 1`. What am I missing?

---

**UPDATE:**
After having a look into the source code I see that the string `find` is set as prefix for the finder method name, so any other scope is not possible. Maybe in an update this could be considered.

So, now I have these 2 possibilites:

1. Adding it into the Table file.
2. Setting a filter in the `Controller`, but this I still didn't figure out how it works. Even I set it in `beforePagination` in the `$event` using `setData( "query", $this->Users->find()->where( ["id" => 1])` this gets ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Solution for question #2:***

In `UsersController.php` in the `index()` method add this:

```
$this->Crud->on('beforePaginate', function(\Cake\Event\EventInterface $event) {
   $this->paginate ['conditions']['id'] = <the-id>;
});
```